# NSPredicate to filter beacon according to UUID, major and minor raising exception

Tags: nspredicate, ibeacon, nscompoundpredicate, clbeacon

I have a **beacons** array having a collection of CLBeacon and I would like to get only the beacon which matches a given uuid, major and minor in NSPredicate. Below is the code in Object C which is generating an exception because of UUID in the predicate. The code works fine if I remove the uuidPredicate from the query.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray<CLBeacon *> *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region{

        NSPredicate *uuidPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uuid.UUIDString == [c] %@", @"03672ce6-9272-48ea-ba54-0bf679217980"];
       //NSPredicate *uuidPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uuid == %@", @"03672ce6-9272-48ea-ba54-0bf679217980"];
        NSPredicate *majorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"major = %ld", 1];
        NSPredicate *minorPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"minor = %ld", 3];

        NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[uuidPredicate, majorPredicate, minorPredicate]];

        NSArray *pointABeacon = [beacons filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];   

    }
```

The beacons array is something like

```
beacons (
    "CLBeacon (uuid:03672CE6-9272-48EA-BA54-0BF679217980, major:1, minor:1, proximity:1 +/- 0.07m, rssi:-61)",
    "CLBeacon (uuid:03672CE6-9272-48EA-BA54-0BF679217980, major:1, minor:2, proximity:1 +/- 0.07m, rssi:-62)",
    "CLBeacon (uuid:03672CE6-9272-48EA-BA54-0BF679217981, major:1, minor:3, proximity:2 +/- 1.64m, rssi:-53)"
)
```

The exception is

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< CLBeacon 0x1c401c410 > valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key uuid.'

How to filter the array with three parameters uuid, major and minor?

Comment: `@"uuid.UUIDString == [c]` => `@ proximityUUID.UUIDString == [c]`? Simply do `CLBeacon *beacon = beacons.firstObject`. And try to write `NSUUID *uuidTest = beacon.uuid` what does XCode says about it? What's the name of the property for the UUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:
A [`CLBeacon`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clbeacon?language=objc) object doesn't have a property named `uuid`.

When you print a `CLBeacon` object, you might see "uuid", but that's not the real name of the property, it's [`proximityUUID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clbeacon/1621508-proximityuuid?language=objc)

So:

```
NSPredicate *uuidPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uuid.UUIDString == [c] %@", @"03672ce6-9272-48ea-ba54-0bf679217980"];
```

should be:

```
NSPredicate *uuidPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"proximityUUID.UUIDString == [c] %@", @"03672ce6-9272-48ea-ba54-0bf679217980"];
```